# How to find the position of item in an embedded object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

In my project, I have a query that returns a list of turns.

There is a one-to-many relationship between the turns and the stores, meaning that a store has many turns that needs to fullfill. Also, a user can have many turns. Here are the shapes of those objects:

```
interface UserInterface {
  id: string;
  fullName: number;
  user: AuthUser;
  turns: Turn[];
}
interface StoreInterface {
  name: string;
  turns: Turn[];
  user: UserInterface;
}
interface Turn {
  id: string;
  fullfilled: boolean;
  user: UserInterface;
  store: StoreInterface;
}
```

My goal is to find out, given the results of the query (a list of turns) and the user ID, in what position of the queue is the user. I tried this solution:

```
 const getTurnPosition = (): number  => {
    let turnPosition: number;
    data.getTurnsForUser.map((turn: Turn) => {
      const turnList = turn.store.turns.filter(
        (turn) => turn.fullfilled === false
      );
      const myTurn = turnList.find(
        (turn: Turn) => turn.user.user.id === userId
      );
      if (myTurn) {
        turnPosition = turnList.indexOf(myTurn);
        return turnPosition;
      }
    });
  };
```

As you can see, I need to first get rid of the turns that are already fullfilled with the `filter()` method. Then, I use the `find()` method in order to get the turn that belongs to the user ID that I have.

But there's a problem with this approach: The function returns `undefined` even though when I `console.log(turnPosition)` and I see the right index. Typescript warns me about this too.

I'm very lost with this. What am I doing wrong?

PD: This is an example of the full query (graphQL):

```
Object {
    "getTurnsForUser": Array [
      Object {
        "__typename": "TurnType",
        "id": "178",
        "store": Object {
          "__typename": "StoreType",
          "name": "Siempre Abierto",
          "turns": Array [
            Object {
              "__typename": "TurnType",
              "fullfilled": true,
              "id": "174",
              "user": Object {
                  "__typename": "AuthUserType",
                  "id": "45",
                  "username": "martin"
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      },
    ],
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning inside your `map` function, but you are never actually returning anything from your `getTurnPosition()` function, which is why it shows `undefined`. You could change it to be like this:

```
const getTurnPosition = (userId: number): number => {
  for (let turn of data.getTurnsForUser) {
    const unfulfilledTurns = turn.store.turns.filter(
      (t) => t.fulfilled === false
    );
    return unfulfilledTurns.findIndex((t) => t.user.id === userId);
  }
};
```

This utilizes [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) since that is what you are interested in,  but also just returns immediately upon finding the first index of the first unfulfilled turn found in some top level `turn`.

If you actually want an array of indices of turn positions for each `store` of turns, you would need to return the `map`, but you would likely want some additional identifying info on which `store` this turn index is referring to.

```
const getTurnPosition = (userId: number): number => {
  return data.getTurnsForUser.map(turn => {
    const unfulfilledTurns = turn.store.turns.filter(
      (t) => t.fulfilled === false
    );
    return unfulfilledTurns.findIndex((t) => t.user.id === userId);
  });
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'll give it a try tomorrow